# How to portably test for a SIGPIPE failure

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, pipe, signals

In a bash script, I have a pipeline of this form

```
/bin/find ... | grep --quiet --max-count=1 .
```

Basically, I am just testing, yes/no, whether `/bin/find` found *anything*.

Therefore, if `/bin/find` fails due to a `SIGPIPE` signal, that should be treated as normal behavior.  I want to distinguish such expected failures from any other failure of `/bin/find` in this pipeline.

I know that, on my system at least, when `/bin/find` receives a `SIGPIPE`, it fails with exit status 141, but I don't know how portable this behavior is.

If it isn't portable, is there some other way I can differentiate between failures from `SIGPIPE` from other failures of `/bin/find`?

Comment: what do you mean by portable? `bash` will always set the exit status (`$?`) of a command that was killed by a signal to 128 + signum (and, of course, any command/script could just fake it by eg. `exit 141`). Other shells may do something not much different. What is not very portable is retrieving the exit status of commands from a pipeline, other than last (which you can do with the `PIPESTATUS` array in bash).

Comment: @mosvy: thank you, your comment answers my question; please post it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Note, to stop on the first find use `find ... -print -quit` and then test the output for empty or not.

Comment: @meuh: that's awesome, thank you!!!